# Excel export ; using VBA, how to export cell as formatted rather than the raw cell value

Tags: excel, export-to-csv, vba

[This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291296/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) shows how to write a small program to surround the cell value in double-quotation marks for a CSV export.

```
' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & """";
```

Is there a way to reference the cell's *formatted* value and write the formatted value out instead?

For example, the raw data could be `8543` but the spreadsheet might have Zip Code formatting applied to the column, so the value is displayed as `08543`.

Comment: well, the formatted value might be for example, BOLD, ITALIC, or in the case of numbers, n,nnn.00 - now how are you going to show that in your output file? Is your output file an MS Word doc, or a text file?

Comment: with your example, you copuld format the data that you're writing out, so you would put format(Selection.Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount).Text, "zip") - is that what you want?

Comment: CSV files are text or flat files, so normally the format wouldn't be output along with the data. Of course, you could add another field storing the format of the row, like a format string for example 'Col 1 = BOLD.ITALIC.VERDANA.10PT; Col 2=0.ITALIC.TAHOMA.8PT; Col 3= 0.0.Times New Roman.18PT'

Comment: The application of the data "mask" to the raw value is another term for what I'm looking for. I don't need "styling"

Comment: Usually you would differentiate between the `Value` property of a `Range` object (i.e. a cell or cells) and the `Text` property of a `Range` object. `Value` is the raw data and `Text` is what is displayed in the cell (in terms of number formats and text formats but not styling as you described it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this - grab the value and then format it as per the selected range's number formatting:

```
Format(Range("A1").Value, Range("A1").NumberFormat)
```

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, thanks, so I'll accept the answer. Not quite as simple as that, because of General formatting.  The Excel sheets are sent to us, we didn't create them. Excel is a quick way to share "data". The formatting of columns is often poorly chosen by the people who created these sheets.

Comment: I don't know how you're going to get the formatted value from that answer into a CSV file, because the data won't include text formatting like Bold, or Zip file mask...you would have to actually pad your raw data with zeroes to turn 5867 into 05867